# How to compute Generalized Group Inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, computational-mathematics

Given a transition matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, i.e. $\sum_j P_{ij} = 1$ and $P_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i,j$. One can show that there exists a unique group inverse $B$ of $A:= I - P$ which fulfills
$$ ABA=A , \, BAB=B, \quad \text{and} \quad AB=BA.  $$

What is the best way to compute $B$ if $A$ is given?